# How can I display Bootstrap progress bar numbers under the bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am able to create [progress bar with Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/progress/).

I want those numerical values to be displayed below the progress bar but not inside, something like this:

[image]

How can we achieve this? Do I need to use any JavaScript graphing libraries?

PS: Note that the main challenge I am facing is to show the numbers below divs, and not with color styling or calculating those numbers.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container pt-4">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 15%;">
      15
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%;">
      45
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 20%;">
      65
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: So you'd want to write the number for each bar, below the lower left corner of that bar? Then where would the "20" in your second example come from? You have three bar segments, but four numbers there ...?

Comment: I wanted to convey the design difference not the difference between actual data. Sorry for the confusion. Now, I synced the two images. Again, note that the main challenge I am facing is to show the numbers below divs, and not with color styling or calculating those numbers.

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version. Your docs link is to a _very_ old version 4.0.0, and your demo loads the latest version 5.

Comment: I'd just wrap the numbers into an additional span, and then position that absolute.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to add a div below yours and to use some JavaScript

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar');
var count = 0;
var values = document.getElementById('values');
var value = document.createElement('div');
value.innerHTML = "0";
value.style.width = (parseInt(elements[0].style.width.split('%')[0]) - 1.6) + "%"
values.appendChild(value);

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  count += parseInt(elements[i].style.width.split('%')[0]);
  //elements[i].innerHTML = count;

  var value = document.createElement('div');
  value.innerHTML = count;

  if (i < elements.length - 1)
    value.style.width = parseInt(elements[i + 1].style.width.split('%')[0]) + "%"
  else
    value.style.width = (100 - count - 4) + "%";
  values.appendChild(value);
}
var value = document.createElement('div');
value.innerHTML = "100";
values.appendChild(value);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 15%;"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%;"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 20%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="values" style="display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap;"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Not bad. I'd encourage you to use `elements.forEach(element => {})` rather than clunky old `for()` with its manual incrementing. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach. Also, use `let` and `const` rather than `var`. I believe you can use `const` for all cases here.

Answer (score 1):

A little CSS whizbang and some pseudo-elements should do. Note that I wrapped the numeric values with spans for positioning. By giving the structure a custom class we can override Bootstrap's styles without using `!important`, which makes work easier down the road and avoids styling *all* progress bars.

Also note that Bootstrap provides classes for position, overflow, and border-radius, but I've put those things in the CSS for clarity. I did use border classes on the outer element.

```css
.progress.labels-out,
.progress.labels-out .progress-bar {
  position: relative; /* allows positioning of child elements */
  overflow: visible; /* lets the child elements be seen */
  border-radius: 0;
}

.progress.labels-out .progress-bar span,
.progress.labels-out::before,
.progress.labels-out::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 5px); /* shift down the height of the parent plus a bit */
  left: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%); /* shift left half its own width to center */
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.progress.labels-out::before {
  content: '100';
}

.progress.labels-out::after {
  content: '0';
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container pt-4">
  <div class="progress labels-out border border-2">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 15%;">
      <span>15</span>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%;">
      <span>45</span>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 20%;">
      <span>65</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, this was indeed great answer. I was guessing if we can add end values (0 and 100) through html, instead of through CSS. I did a bit a tweaking, since mine max value wont always be 100. So I removed `content: '100'` from CSS and added another progress bar to fill up remaining space. So, in your example, I added another `div` with `style="width: 35%;"` and `<span>100</span>` to fill up the remaining space. With this we can have any number labels calculated with some maths. For example, labels `15,45,65,100` can be replaced with `3,13,17,24` and those widths will still be correct for them.